# Running Ngen on EntityFramework.Dll v 6.1 produces error windows 10

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, windows-10, ngen

I am running Ngen on my EntityFramework.dll version 6.1 as  Entity Framework does not come in the default installation of the .net Framework. Therefore, the EF assembly is not NGEN'd which means that EF code needs to be JITTED each time the application starts.

So in my windows 8 Environment i run the following command in the developer command prompt

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install C:\Code\Bin\EntityFramework.dll
```

This runs fin in Windows 8 Environment.

BUT in Windows 10 I get the following error

"Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file"

I have tried adding the following to my machine.config

```
  <runtime>
    <developmentMode developerInstallation="false"/>
  </runtime>
```

But this has not solved the issue.

Any Ideas?

Comment: for me it works. Let NuGet download the EF DLL again (Package restore).